# Input: Avoid losing focus for touch on screen keyboard

Tags: angular, events

As statet, I have input fields (atm Angular Material) inside a form container (`mat-form-field`).
I try to use a custom on screen keyboard (simple-keyboard). However, I want the keyboard to open when the input field is focused and to close when it is not focused anymore:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="input"
           type="number" formControlName="inputControl"
           #inputControl
           (focus)="showKeyboard =true"
           (blur)="showKeyboard=false"
    >
  </mat-form-field>
  <app-keyboard [style.display]="showKeyboard ? 'inline' : 'none'" 
                [inputName]="'inputControl'"
                (input)="inputControl.value=$event"></app-keyboard>
```

The problem is that for touch (or I don't know) events on the keyboard, the `blur` event of the input field seems to be triggered, and the keyboard is thus closed at each keystroke.

I've tried manually avoid bubbling of the `focus` and `click` events for the keyboard with `(focus)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation()"` but this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the click event  for mobile. On clicking inside the input element, open the keyboard and when clicking outside close the keyboard.

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event']) clickedOutside(ev: any) {
    if (this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(ev.target)) {
      this.showKeyboard = true;
    } else {
      this.showKeyboard = false;
    }
  }
```

while the elementRef is your input. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, how would this prevent the keyboard from closing? Wouldn't a click inside the keyboard still close it?

Comment: I haven't thought about that. I guess you can add another elementRef for the keyboard too and only clicks outside of both the input and the keyboard should close it.

Comment: Here's a demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5khceb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the demo. But it seems, that it is not a click event that causes the blur.

Comment: I was suggesting to use the click event for opening and closing the keyboard on mobile devices, instead the focus and blur. Cheers

Comment: Ok, it is not really how I intended to solve it, but thanks for the workaround. ... +1